# AWS IAM Role permission issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-iot

We have just built a new Things Enterprise server hosted at AWS on an EC2 instance and created an application to use AWS IOT. We are getting the following error

“message”: “User: arn:aws:sts::446971925991:assumed-role/Things-Enterprise-Stack-Srv-StackIAMRole-DBHBSMSY05AQ/i-095895d605fab3fa4 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::446971925991:role/Bosh-Parking-IOT-Stack-TheThingsStackRoleCD9FBAD2-C44RRJJ53M93”

I have been told

> What is the execution role of the TTES instance that is trying to assume the role? The role TTES needs to be able to assume that role. That will give the right permissions.

But I'm not sure what that means, i'm presuming i need to add / alter some permissions within an IAM role. Can someone point me in the right direction Pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it seems that your [IAM role for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#working-with-iam-roles) has **no permissions to assume a role** `Bosh-Parking-IOT-Stack-TheThingsStackRoleCD9FBAD2-C44RRJJ53M93`.

To add such permissions **manually** you can do the following:

1. Go to `IAM Console->Roles`.
2. In the `Roles` window, you can use `Search` bar to locate `Things-Enterprise-Stack-Srv-StackIAMRole-DBHBSMSY05AQ` role.
3. Once you find the role, you click on  [Add inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html).
4. Once `Create policy` window shows, you can go to `JSON tab` and add the following JSON policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAssumeRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::446971925991:role/Bosh-Parking-IOT-Stack-TheThingsStackRoleCD9FBAD2-C44RRJJ53M93"
        }
    ]
}
```

5. Then click `Review Policy`, name the policy (e.g. PolicyToAssumeRole) and `Create policy`

However, based on your policy names (e.g. Stack-Srv-StackIAMRole) it is possible that they have been create by **CloudFormation**. If this is the case, then manually changing the roles as described above is a **bad practice** and will lead to [drift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html). Any changes to resources created by CloudFormation **should be done using CloudFormation**. Sadly, your question does not provide any details about CloudFormation templates used, therefore its difficult to comment on that more.

Comment: Hi, You are indeed correct the deployment was via a Cloud formation template. We have used the official AWS Things Enterprise Stack which can be viewed here - https://enterprise.thethingsstack.io/getting-started/aws/ami/

I will get in touch and see if the addition / change can be made via a template update. Thanks for the pointers

Comment: Hi @Marcin, i just added the policy as per your suggestion just to try it with a view that we can add it to the template later on. However still getting the same error message

"message": "User: arn:aws:sts::446971925991:assumed-role/Things-Enterprise-Stack-Srv-StackIAMRole-DBHBSMSY05AQ/i-095895d605fab3fa4 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::446971925991:role/Bosh-Parking-IOT-Stack-TheThingsStackRoleCD9FBAD2-C44RRJJ53M93"

Comment: @Pigsfoot Intresting. For tests, can you allow all resources in the policy? `"Resource": "*"`

Comment: Perfect, thats cracked it.... no more error messages. Thanks for your help, much appreciated. We'll look into updating the template now.